# Using definite clause grammars in Picat

Tags: grammar, dcg, picat

I know that it is possible to define [definite clause grammars in Picat](https://github.com/hakank/hakank/blob/master/picat/dcg_test.pi), but the syntax is much more verbose than in Prolog. In Prolog, definite clause grammars can be written more concisely:

```
pronoun --> him,her,it.
```

Surprisingly, [Picat's official tutorial](http://picat-lang.org/download/picat_tutorial.pdf) doesn't mention a syntax for definite clause grammars. Would it be possible to use Prolog's DCG notation in Picat?

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea. This is simple DCG converter for Picat.
This code is example file of DCG like format.

```
dcg([sentence, -->, noun_phrase, verb_phrase]).
dcg([noun_phrase, -->, det, noun]).
dcg([verb_phrase, -->, verb, noun_phrase]).
dcg([det, -->, [the]]).
dcg([det, -->, [a]]).
dcg([det, -->, [an]]).
dcg([noun, -->, [cat]]).
dcg([noun, -->, [bat]]).
dcg([verb, -->, [eats]]).
```

Next code is main.pi file.

```
import util, io.

main([IN]) =>
  writeln([IN.to_atom()]),
  rw_dcg(IN.to_atom()).

rw_dcg(RF) =>
  RD = open(RF),
  I = 1,
  MP = new_map(),
  L = read_term(RD),
  while (L != end_of_file)
    DCG=cnv_dcg(I,MP,L),
    cl_facts(DCG),
    println(L),
    println(DCG),
    L := read_term(RD),
    I := I+1
  end,
  close(RD).
cnv_dcg(_,MP,dcg([HD,-->,[a]])) =DCG,
  Q=check_lhs(MP,HD) =>
  % I don't know this code problem of "a", and why?.
  DCG = HD.to_string()++"([a|X],X2)"++Q++"=> X2=X.".
cnv_dcg(_,MP,dcg([HD,-->,T])) =DCG,
  list(T),
  Q=check_lhs(MP,HD) =>
  append(T2,[_],T.to_string()),
  DCG = HD.to_string()++"("++T2++"|X],X2)"++Q++"=> X2=X.".
cnv_dcg(_,MP,dcg([HD,-->|T])) =DCG =>
  LN = (T.length()+1).to_string(),
  DCG = HD.to_string()++"(S1,S"++LN++") => ",
  foreach(I in 1..T.length())
    E=cond(I==T.length(),".",",").to_string(),
    N1 = I.to_string(),
    N2 = (I+1).to_string(),
    DCG := DCG++T[I].to_string()++"(S"++N1++",S"++N2++")"++E.

check_lhs(MP,KY)= Q =>
  (MP.has_key(KY)-> Q=" " ; Q=" ?", MP.put(KY,Q)).
```

Next is converted code. Thank you for deleted and comments.

```
sentence(S1,S3) => noun_phrase(S1,S2),verb_phrase(S2,S3).
noun_phrase(S1,S3) => det(S1,S2),noun(S2,S3).
verb_phrase(S1,S3) => verb(S1,S2),noun_phrase(S2,S3).
det([the|X],X2) ?=> X2=X.
det([a|X],X2) => X2=X.
det([an|X],X2) => X2=X.
noun([cat|X],X2) ?=> X2=X.
noun([bat|X],X2) => X2=X.
verb([eats|X],X2) ?=> X2=X.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 3.0 (September 26, 2020), Picat supports DCG rules natively: http://picat-lang.org/updates.txt